# System verilog constraints

Tags: constraints, verilog, system-verilog

Write a constraint for two random variables such that one
variable should not match with the other & the total number of bits
toggled in one variable should be 5 w.r.t the other

please , can anyone write constraint for this question

Answer (score 2):

I assume by *toggled* you mean they are different from each other in a particular bit position. Use the XNOR bitwise operator `~^`.

```
module top;
  class A;
    rand bit [9:0] rv1,rv2;
    constraint c1 { $countones(rv1 ~^ rv2) == 5; }
  endclass
  
  A h = new;
  initial repeat (10) begin
    assert(h.randomize);
    $displayb(h.rv1,,h.rv2);
  end
endmodule
```